# My Symbol is Lost in the Maze

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, undefined-symbol

I am creating a maze game as part of a university assessment. I've intended to loop through the maze board until I find the character `'&'` and then return the y coordinate of the player (I've done the same method for getting the x position and getting the same error)

The error I am getting:

```
MazeGame.java:133: error: cannot find symbol  
return i;  
^  
symbol:   variable i  
location: class MazeGame  
1 error
```

And, my code,

```
public static int getCurrentYPosition() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < board[i].length; n++) {
            if (board[i][n] == '&') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Why can't it find the symbol?

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` isn't in scope **after** the loop. `return` when you find it, and handle the case where the character isn't found with a sentinel (like `-1`). And, as written the `break` would only apply to the ***inner*** loop (so if we make `i` visible by increasing its' scope, for example) you would then `return` `numberOfRows` as `i` increments until then. So, I think you really wanted something like

```
public static int getCurrentYPosition() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < board[i].length; n++) {
            if (board[i][n] == '&') {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that you could also write it with a `for-each` loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    for (char ch : board[i]) {
        if (ch == '&') {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: You do know that this code is different from the original code, right? The `break` in the original code only broke the inner loop (though that doesn't actually make sense), and if `i` had still been in scope, as was likely intended, the return statement would return `numberOfRows`, not `-1`. I agree your code makes more sense, but you should mention those changes to the logic in the answer. Still, +1.